# Add and populate an IEnumerable property to an API call

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I'm using an older 3rd party API to connect to a legacy system.

Here is the code:

```
    AutoMaximizer.AuthUser yourCredentials = new AutoMaximizer.AuthUser
    {
        UserKey = "x1213"
    };

    AutoMaximizer.Pagers availableCars = new AutoMaximizer.Pagers
    {
        TotalCalls = 65,
        Router = 91220
    };

    ISessionManagement s = new ManagementClient();

    FactoryResponse response;

    response = await s.GetAll(yourCredentials, new ListRequest
    {
        Pagers = availableCars,
        SortIncreasing = true
    });
```

It's working, but I want to add another property when I make the request.

The property is called `Types` and is a `IEnumerable<Type>`.  The API docs state:

```
Types   =  Gets or sets an enumeration of types to include in the response.
```

And in the API reference, I found it:

```
public enum Type : int
{
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Auto = 0,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Truck = 1,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Motorcycle = 2
    
}
```

But I'm not quite sure how to add it to the `GetAll` method.

I tried adding this:

```
List<AutoMaximizer.Type> types = new List<AutoMaximizer.Type>();
types.Add(AutoMaximizer.Type.Auto);
types.Add(AutoMaximizer.Type.Truck);
types.Add(AutoMaximizer.Type.Motorcycle);
```

And then this:

```
response = await s.GetAll(yourCredentials, new ListRequest
{
    Pagers = availableCars,
    SortIncreasing = true,
    Types = types
});
```

But that gives me this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type Systems.Collections.Generic.List<AutoMaximizer.Type> to AutoMaximizer.Type[]
```

I am not sure what to do now...

Is there a way to get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read your error, it wants an array, not a list:

```
response = await s.GetAll(yourCredentials, new ListRequest
{
    Pagers = availableCars,
    SortIncreasing = true,
    Types = new[] { Type.Auto, Type.Truck, Type.Motorcycle },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the error, the `ListRequest` is specifically looking for an array, not any generic collection.  You can convert the list to an array:

```
response = await s.GetAll(yourCredentials, new ListRequest
{
    Pagers = availableCars,
    SortIncreasing = true,
    Types = types.ToArray()
});
```

Or just use an array to begin with:

```
AutoMaximizer.Type[] types = new [] { AutoMaximizer.Type.Auto, AutoMaximizer.Type.Truck, AutoMaximizer.Type.Motorcycle };
```